# SQL query problem in WHERE clause, this returns all that start with

Tags: sql, where-clause

I've written the following SQL query to return all sites having "id" equal to 2.

`` SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE id = '2' ``

And it works well. The problem is that even if I add some characters after "2" like this :

`` SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE id = '2etyupp-7852-trG78' ``

It returns the same results as above.

How to avoid this ? that's to say return none on the second query ?

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: ``SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE id = 2``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are mixing types:

```
where id = '2'
------^ number
-----------^ string
```

What is a SQL engine supposed to do?  Well, the standard approach is to convert the *string* to a *number*.  So this is run as:

```
where id = 2
```

What happens when the string is not a number?  In most databases, you get a type conversion error.  However, MySQL does *implicit conversion*, converting the leading digits to a number.  Hence, your second string just comes `2`.

From this, I hope you learn not to mix data types.  Compare numbers to numbers.  Compare strings to strings.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I understand it very well now.